# MySQL Query for deleting entries

Tags: mysql

I have a Account-Database with a "last-login" row, I want to delete all accounts which are empty (NULL) at last-login row.

Does someone know a MySQL Query for this? (Database-Structure is like: User-Id, password, last-login)

Comment: I removed php-tag, because no php related question IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from Account-Database where `last-login` is NULL;
```

It's not clear in your question whether Account-Database is the table name or the database name but you get the idea.

Comment: In SQL, `NULL=NULL` is `NULL`, not `false`.

Comment: correct sql will be more like `delete from Account-Database where last-login is NULL` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the the tricks:

```
DELETE FROM Account-Database WHERE last-login IS NULL;
```

or if the field is just an empty field (not `null` but `''`)

```
DELETE FROM Account-Database WHERE last-login= '';
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
mysql_query("Delete from Account-Database where last-login = NULL");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `Account-Database` WHERE `last-login` IS NULL;
```

The syntax for a DELETE query is as follows:

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE conditions
```